# How to exclude files from Istanbul nyc coverage report

Tags: reactjs, cypress, istanbul, nyc

I am just trying to get the basic Istanbul nyc exclude functionality working on my project but so far I cannot.

I am using Cypress to run e2e test on my react.js application. My coverage report seems to be working fine other than it not ignoring the files in my exclude array.

I have tried adding this to my `package.json` file:

```
"nyc": {
        "exclude": [
            "AddressFormatter.js"
        ]
    }
```

I have tried including the full path name `src/components/AddressFormatter` as well as `**/AddressFormatter.js`.

I have also tried using a `.nycrc.json` with the following content:

```
{
    "reporter": ["lcov", "text-summary"],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "instrument": true,
    "temp-dir": "app/test/.nyc_output",
    "report-dir": "app/test/coverage",
    "all": true,
    "exclude": ["**/AddressFormatter.js"],
    "check-coverage": true
}
```

The steps I took to find this problem. From the terminal I ran

`yarn add -D @cypress/code-coverage`

Then I ran

`yarn add -D nyc`

Next I ran

`nyc instrument ./src ./coverage`

Lastly I updated the `package.json` start script with

`"start": "react-scripts -r @cypress/instrument-cra start"`

After this I tried all of the methods above to get my coverage report to ignore different files.

So far I have had no success ignoring this file. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following the docs seems that there are a couple of options you can try:

- Add the exclude option into your code coverage environment variable:

```js
// cypress.config.js or cypress.json
env: {
  codeCoverage: {
    exclude: ['**/AddressFormatter.*'],
  },
},
```

- Use the `excludeAfterRemap`  option. Quoting the repo `README`:

> Another important option is excludeAfterRemap. By default it is false, which might let excluded files through. If you are excluding the files, and the instrumenter does not respect the nyc.exclude setting, then add excludeAfterRemap: true to tell nyc report to exclude files.

- Lastly there is an example [repo](https://github.com/cypress-io/code-coverage/blob/master/test-apps/new-cypress-config/exclude-files) you can compare yours with

Comment: Placing an exclude array in my `cypress.json` seems to work, however it also caused a bunch of new unstyled build and coverage folders to be added to my coverage report.

Comment: I guess cypress does the coverage for you so running `nyc instrument ./src ./coverage` makes things duplicate. Can you try online running the cypress command?

Comment: I found a work around for the issue I stated above. Everything is working now thanks.